# How can i change value in class using other value

Tags: python, class

So i have this code and i want to set veolcity iun run method to maxSpeed * 0.75, but i cant use this value. Can anyone explain me why so?

```
    class Car:
        def __init__(self, brand, model, year, maxSpeed, velocity, colour, plates):
            self.brand = brand
            self.model = model
            self.year = year
            self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
            self.velocity = velocity
            self.colour = colour
            self.plates = plates
    


        def setColour(self, colour):
            self.colour = colour

        def run(self,velocity):
            self.velocity = maxSpeed * 0.75

        def stop(self, velocity):
            self.velocity = 0
    

    car1 = Car("BMW","M5",2023,250, 0, "blue","23442JK")
    print(car1)
```

Comment: Explain "can't use this value". What happens, what should happen? Show error messages (if any) completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `maxSpeed` is undefined; did you mean `self.maxSpeed`? You don't use the `velocity` argument to `run`; it can probably be omitted.

Comment: Your question is not clear, you need to specify what code do you use, what is the desired result, what is the actual result? By the way, I think the problem here is just that you need to use `self.maxSpeed` not `maxSpeed`

Comment: Well , i text compiler cant see this value. In the code i paste above value maxSpeed in run method is inactive

Comment: `self.velocity` should probably be initialized to 0 until you actually call a method to make the car go. Cars aren't photons: they aren't moving the instant they are created :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self.maxSpeed` to access the instance attribute. Having "velocity" as a parameter is unnecessary, as it's not used in your function:

```
def run(self): 
    self.velocity = self.maxSpeed * 0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `run` method you are trying to implement would look like this:

```py
...
def run(self):
    self.velocity = self.maxSpeed * 0.75
...
```

The `velocity` parameter you included in your example above is never referenced and `maxSpeed` is not defined in the scope of your implementation (`self.maxSpeed` is not the same as `maxSpeed`). By using `self`, you reference the object itself and have access to the properties of your `Car` instance.